# Using CSS, how do I keep a "frame" centered, and align things within the frame

Tags: html, css, web, alignment

On the webpage, I would like to create a virtual frame (centered about the page) and be able to align elements (e.g images, text, etc) within the frame using CSS properties.

Since a picture is worth a thousand words, this is what I mean:

[image]

I'd want to be able to align "Text1" to the left with respect to the virtual frame which is kept centered about the webpage. Similar idea with "CenteredText" and the blue box being aligned to the right relative to the frame.

I'd really appreciate suggestions on how I'd be able to do this.

Comment: Simple `float:right;` isn't enough ?

Comment: The majority of CSS rules that change where an element is rendered do so within that element's container.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="frame">
    <div>Text1</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered text</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.frame{width:80%; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #444; height:500px}
.centered{text-align:center}
.box{background:blue; height:50px; width:50px; border:2px solid black; float:right}
.clr{clear:both}
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/fqaDQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

in your css.

You need a div with a class or id you can attack to and then give it the above property.

This will centre the div in the page.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="left">left</div>

<div id="centered">centre</div>

<div id="right">right</div>
</div> <!--close wrapper-->
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}

#left{
    float: left;
}
#right{
    float: right;
}
```

Good luck!